# How to Loop Through API Calls

Tags: javascript, testing, request

I am trying to loop through coordinates of an API endpoint and test each response. When I send the request when it is not nested in for loops it works just fine, however, it doesn't seem to send when nested.

How can I automate the testing of this endpoint with various coordinates?

```
const request = require('request')
const domain = 'host.local'
const port = '8085'
const url = 'http://' + domain + ':' + port + '/v1/vend/item'

const parameters = {
 coordinate: {
   x: null,
   y: null
 },
 network: {
   user: "config",
   role: "admin"
 }
}

const x_coordinates = [1,2,3,4,5]
const y_coordinates = [6,7,8,9,10]

let options = {
  method: 'post',
  body: parameters,
  json: true,
  url: url
}

for (item in x_coordinates) {
  parameters.coordinate.x = parseInt(item) + 1
  for (item in y_coordinates.length) {
    parameters.coordinate.y = parseInt(item) + 7
    sleep(10000)

    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
      var headers = res.headers
      var statusCode = res.statusCode
    })
  }
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Alternative promise method

```
for(let i=0; i<x_coordinates.length; i++) {
  body.coordinate.x = i
  for(let j=0; j<y_coordinates.length; j++) {
    body.coordinate.y = j

    let options = {
      url: 'http://' + domain + ':' + port + '/v1/vend/item',
      method: 'post',
      json: true,
      body: body
    }

    ps.push(rp(options))

  }
}

Promise.all(ps)
  .then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

This implementation of promises sent all the requests at once. They need a delay between them. Ideally, once the first request gets a response, the second is sent.

Comment: Should never use `for in` on arrays and that sleep approach is horrible. Learn how to use promises

Comment: Why is sleep horrible?

Comment: sleep can lead to really inconsistent results. Use Promises. Use .map to iterate and create an array of Promises. After loop is finished, use Promise.all to wait for all promises to resolve and "then" work on the data received.

Comment: Please see above for a promise implementation. The requests just overloaded my test hardware. The requests need to be spaced out.

Comment: The API is doing mechanical switching so the requests can't be brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a little helper function called `chainAsync`:

https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-code#chainasync

Here it is written a bit less densely:

```
function chainAsync(arrayOfFunctions){
  let currentFunctionIndex = 0
  const lastFunction = arrayOfFunctions[arrayOfFunctions.length - 1]
  goToNextFunction()

  function goToNextFunction(){
    const currentFunction = arrayOfFunctions[currentFunctionIndex]
    if(currentFunction == lastFunction){
        currentFunction()
    }else{
        currentFunction(goToNextFunction)
        currentFunctionIndex += 1
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
chainAsync([
  function(goToNextFunction){
    request(options, (err, res, body)=>{
      // Handle the response. Then...
      goToNextFunction()
    })
  },
  function(goToNextFunction){
    request(options, (err, res, body)=>{
      // Handle the response. Then...
      goToNextFunction()
    })
  },
  function(){
    request(options, (err, res, body)=>{
      // Handle the response. Then...
      // ...don't go to next function, since there isn't a next function!
    })
  }
])
```

This way you have control over the order in which these asynchronous functions take place.

Here's one way of using it to address your use-case:

```
const requestsToExecute = []

x_coordinates.forEach(x=>{
    y_coordinates.forEach(y=>{

        const currentRequest = function(goToNextRequest){
            const requestOptions = {
                url: 'http://host.local:8085/v1/vend/item',
                method: 'POST',
                json: true,
                body: {
                    coordinate: {x, y},
                    network: {
                        user: 'config',
                        role: 'admin'
                    }
                }
            }
            request(requestOptions, (err, response, body)=>{
                // Handle the response, then...
                // ...if there's another request...
                if(goToNextRequest){
                    // ...use setTimeout to wait 1e7 seconds before going to the next request
                    setTimeout(goToNextRequest, 1e7)
                }
            })
        }
        requestsToExecute.push(currentRequest)

    })
})

chainAsync(requestsToExecute)
```

Comment: Hm... I'm trying to call the same function 60+ times with a few with a different body and few second delay each time.

Comment: @Matthew I've updated my response to address your specific use-case.

Comment: Close... but it loops through all coordinates before sending the first request.

Comment: And just sends the last coordinates over and over again.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you Robert!!